# Using associations with pluck

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to get an array with the project name and task title. The task title is in the projects model. Should I use pluck or a select or where?

```
@completed_tasks = Task.where(completed:true).select("projects.project_name", :title)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use `join` to get data from *projects* table.
And then you can use either `pluck` or `select`.

For example (suppose in your `Task` model you have `belongs_to :project`)

```rb
@completed_tasks = Task.where(completed:true).join(:project).select("projects.project_name", :title)
```

Comment: I do have belongs_to :project. I set up the models associations already. When I use your code I "get no implicit conversion of Symbol into String"

Comment: What version of Rails? Try `select('projects.project_name, title')`

Answer (score 0):

```
@completed_tasks = Task.where(completed:true).joins(:project).pluck("projects.project_name", :title)
```